# How we can use a parameter variable outside the function without storing it into another variable?

Tags: java

How we can use a parameter variable outside the function without storing it into another variable? 
example: SAY if i want to read the value by user input as a parameter??

```
public class CC {

    public int f(int a, int b) {
        int d, c;
        d = a;
        c = b;
        return a + b;
    } // want to use a & b outside

    public int q(int a, int b) {
        return a + b; // re-initial-is- will delete the previous parameter value;
    }

    public int w() {
        int p = a + b; // error:cannot access or resolve a & b into variables
        return p;
    }

    public int e() {
        int u = d + c; // works but this is not the solution
        return u;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CC obj = new CC();
        obj.f(3, 4);
        obj.q(8, 9);
        obj.w();
        obj.e();
    }

}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` should be field of your class.

Comment: "without storing it into another variable" -> assuming a field also counts as a "variable", you're left with storing a file on disk, or asking a user to type something in again later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How we can use a parameter variable outside the function without storing it into another variable?

It's not possible. The scope of the local variables are confined to the method in which they are  declared. All the local variables are stored on the stack frame for that method. When the method returns, the stack frame is destroyed, and thus all the local variables and parameters are lost.

Quote from [JVM Specification - Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6):

> A frame is used to store data and partial results, as well as to
>   perform dynamic linking, return values for methods, and dispatch
>   exceptions.
>
> A new frame is created each time a method is invoked. **A frame is
>   destroyed when its method invocation completes**, whether that
>   completion is normal or abrupt (it throws an uncaught exception).
>   Frames are allocated from the Java Virtual Machine stack (§2.5.2) of
>   the thread creating the frame. Each frame has its own array of local
>   variables (§2.6.1), its own operand stack (§2.6.2), and a reference to
>   the run-time constant pool (§2.5.5) of the class of the current
>   method.

---

Having said that, it seems like `a` and `b` should really be fields of your class. And then you set them by either passing arguments to your constructor, or by setter methods. This is how you write an Object oriented code. Go through the [**Oracle tutorial on Classes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).

For e.g, take a simple class:

```
class Operation {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Operation(int a, int b) { 
        this.a = a; this.b = b;
    }

    public int sum() {
        return a + b;
    } 
}
```

Now, you create an instance of this class by passing the arguments, that will be later on used in the `sum()` method:

```
Operation operation = new Operation(4, 5);
System.out.println(operation.sum());
```

You can modify your class along this line. And please choose a better name for your class and variables. Also follow standard Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Create **fields** for `a` and `b`, and initialize them in `f()` with the parameters.

E.g., like this:

```
public class CC{

private int a;
private int b;
private int d;
private int c;

public int f(int a,int b)
 {
  d=a;
  c=b;
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
 return a+b; 
 } //want to use a & b outside

public int q(int a, int b)
 {
   return a+b; //re-initial-is- will delete the previous parameter value;
  }

public int w(){
 int p=a+b; //error:cannot access or resolve a & b into variables
 return p;
 }

public int e(){
 int u=d+c; //works but this is not the solution

 return u;
}

 public static void main(String args[]){
 CC obj=new CC();
 System.out.println(obj.f(3,4));
 System.out.println(obj.q(8,9));
 System.out.println(obj.w());
 System.out.println(obj.e());
 } 
}
```

This will print the following to the console:

```
7
17
7
7
```

However, usage of the fields should depend on what you are trying to do.

E.g., if you would want to use *a* and *b* once (for calculating *a* + *b*), then reset them with new values, and be able to use both the old and the new values, you would need to do something like this:

```
package test;

public class CC {

private int a;
private int b;
private int d;
private int c;

public int f(int initialA, int initialB) {
    this.a = initialA;
    this.b = initialB;
    return a+b; 
} //want to use a & b outside

public int q(int resetA, int resetB) {
    // Move values for a + b to other variables for re-use
    this.c = a;
    this.d = b;
    this.a = resetA;
    this.b = resetB;
    return a+b; //re-initial-is- will delete the previous parameter value;
}

public int w() {
    // Use the initial values
    int p = c + d;
    return p;
}

public int e() {
    // Use the reset values
    int u = a + b; //works but this is not the solution
    return u;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    CC obj = new CC();
    System.out.println(obj.f(3,4));
    System.out.println(obj.q(8,9));
    System.out.println(obj.w());
    System.out.println(obj.e());
} 
}
```

This will print the following to the console:

```
7
17
7
17
```